# Invalid tld file see JSP specification section 7.3.1 for more details когда оставляю линк на tld в jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet, tag

Я создал tag library descriptor ( tld ) и поместил его в папку `WEB-INF/tags/`.
Он выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">

<taglib>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>1.2</jsp-version>
    <short-name>simple</short-name>
    <uri>http://tomcat.apache.org/example-taglib</uri>
    <description>A simple tab library for the examples</description>

   

     <tag>
            <name>printImageDirectory</name>
            <tag-class>tag.ImageDirectoryTag</tag-class>
            <attribute>
                <name>dishId</name>
                <required>true</required>
            </attribute>
    
            <attribute>
            <name>imageFileName</name>
                <required>true</required>
            </attribute>
        </tag>
    </taglib>
```

Но вот проблема, когда я пытаюсь связать его с JSP вот так:

```
<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/tags/mytags.tld" prefix="m" %>
```

У меня вот эта ошибка

> Unable to find taglib [m] for URI: [WEB-INF/tags/mytags.tld]

И ссылка не может быть resolved.[image]

Я могу легко исправить это, добавив лишнюю  `/` в начале, чтобы это выглядело так

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tags/mytags.tld" prefix="m" %>
```

И все ошибки компиляции пропадают, но когда я теперь пытаюсь перейти на страницу - ловлю эту ошибку

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Invalid tld file:
> [/WEB-INF/tags/mytags.tld], see JSP specification section 7.3.1 for
> more details

Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Это может быть нерелевантно, но вот сам тэг, который я использовал в tld.

```
public class ImageDirectoryTag extends TagSupport {
    private int dishId;
    private String imageFileName;

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() {
        String dir = String.format("/%s/%s/%s", IMAGES_DIR, dishId, imageFileName);
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();

        try {
            out.print(dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    public void setDishId(int dishId) {
        this.dishId = dishId;
    }

    public void setImageFileName(String imageFileName) {
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В спецификации указано, что в `/WEB-INF/tags` не могут находиться `.tld` файлы.

Более детально можно посмотреть в [Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html).

> Файлы дескрипторов библиотеки тегов имеют имена с расширением `.tld`, а расширение указывает на файл дескриптора библиотеки тегов.  При развертывании внутри файла JAR файлы дескрипторов библиотеки тегов должны находиться в каталоге `META-INF` или его подкаталоге.  При развертывании непосредственно в веб-приложении файлы дескрипторов библиотеки тегов всегда должны находиться в каталоге `WEB-INF` или в каком-либо его подкаталоге.  Файлы TLD не следует помещать в `/WEB-INF/classes` или `/WEB-INF/lib`, а также **нельзя помещать в `/WEB-INF/tags`** или его подкаталог, если он не имеет имени `implicit.tld` и не предназначен для настройки неявной  библиотеки тегов с ее версией JSP и tlib-версией.

Переименуйте папку как-нибудь по другому, скажем `tlds` или перенесите файл tld в `/WEB-INF/`.